# Sharing location between two apps using firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io, expo, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app in which i am using react-native-maps.I want to send the current location to firebase like it’s been done on this article using socketIO https://medium.com/@joycecyoj01/how-to-build-a-location-sharing-feature-using-react-native-and-socket-io-496413ee8065. Also i want to alert all users when one user has passed 100 meter from the current location. How can i do that?
I’d like to know if anyone have come across an article that describes something similar in the article using firebase